# How to specify uniform distribution with same properties as normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, mixture-distribution, marginal-distribution, symmetry

What I mean is, is it possible to specify a uniform random variable $U$ with random parameters $a,b$, where $a=-b$, and are generated from some other distribution, such that the marginal pdf of $U(a,b)$ is a normal distribution pdf with a desired expected value and variance (say 1 for both)? For any arbitrary fixed $a,b$ however, $U$ would obviously still have a uniform pdf.

Comment: You want a uniform distribution with the same mean and variance as a given normal distribution?

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim Not quite, since a uniform would have a finite support [a,b] whereas I'm looking for a combination of uniform with something else, so that the EV and variance of that combination would be "normal" with same support as normal distribution

Answer (score 7):

All symmetric unimodal densities can be represented as scale mixtures of uniforms $\mathcal{U}(-a,a)$ [(Berger and Sellke, 1984)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2289131). For instance, for the Normal $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution, the mixture decomposition
$$(2\pi)^{-1/2}\exp\{-x^2/2\}=\int \frac{1}{2a}\mathbb{I}_{|x|<a}\,\nu(a)\,\text{d}a$$
leads to
$$(2\pi)^{-1/2}\exp\{-x^2/2\}=\int_{|x|}^\infty \frac{1}{2a} \nu(a)\,\text{d}a$$
and by derivation in $x>0$:
$$(2\pi)^{-1/2}x\exp\{-x^2/2\}=\frac{1}{2x}\nu(x)$$
Hence,$$\nu(a)=2(2\pi)^{-1/2}a^2\exp\{-a^2/2\}\mathbb{I}_{a>0}$$
is the mixing density, a squared Gamma $\mathcal{G}(3/2,1/2)$ distribution. Indeed, by the change of variable $u=a^2$, one obtains the density
$$\tilde{\nu}(u)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}u^{\overbrace{{1-1/2}}^{=3/2-1}}\exp\{-u/2\}\mathbb{I}_{u>0}$$
This means that the Normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution can be decomposed as
$$X|U\sim\mathcal{U}(\mu-\sigma U,\mu+\sigma U)
\quad
U^2\sim\mathcal{G}(3/2,1/2)$$

Comment: Sorry what are the characters with subscripts $|x|<a$ and $a>0$? They won't display on my browser. I will have to read more about scale mixtures...but can you just explain the last line a bit more? Are $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ special (ie "named") functions/distributions? And which do I use to generate $a$?

Comment: It's a blackboard $\text{I}$ (denoting the indicator function). $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{G}$ would be uniform and gamma respecitively